# Google code php clone

Tags: php, svn, google-code

I am looking for a *google code*/*beanstalk* php clone that I could install on my server

Does that exists ?

I have tried Indefero, but it is a big pain to install it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit: what are the key features you are looking for? E.g. are you looking for a bug tracker, a wiki, a version control system or some combination of them? Also do you specifically need SVN support? Also why you need to install it to your own server? Is it because you want to make a private repository or for some other reason?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a private repository and be independant of those commercial services, even when they've free plans...
I don't look for something very complex: A svn browser mainly, a wiki and a bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mtrack http://bitbucket.org/wez/mtrack/wiki/Home Trac ported to PHP

Answer (score 2):

Above someone recommended Trac, which I use everyday. I can also recommend redmine - http://www.redmine.org/ . Based on ROR, and seems more developed.

Answer (score 1):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) could be an option for you. I have very good experiences of using Trac as an SVN browser, but also as a project wiki and as a bug tracker. If you install Trac to your own server, you can create an independent, completely private installation of it.

Of course before installing Trac you also need to have [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) installed to your server. This is the downside with practically any self-hosted solutions: you need to take care of the installation and maintance yourself.

Comment: +1 it's Python and not PHP but it's one of the best and easiest around.